# View a website with restricted port access

Tags: networking, internet, port-forwarding, port

I'm designing a website, and I'd like to test my website **from the point of view of a user which has port 80 and 443 open only.** (e.g. hotspot in a restaurant, etc.)

Why? Because my website uses some internal ports, with some forwarding inside Apache, reverse proxy, etc. and I'm not sure how it would look like from a computer which can only access 80 and 443.

How to do that from Windows and Linux? i.e. :

**How to temporarily block all ports except 80 and 443?** (without having to mess too much with configuration)

I'm using Windows 7 and Linux Debian 8.

I was thinking about [such solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/127863/manually-closing-a-port-from-commandline) but didn't know which one to use and also this is maybe too definitive for just a small test to see how my site will react from the point of view of a user who has only 80 and 443 open...

Comment: What have you tried?  How you block specific ports on Windows depends on the firewall your using.  How you block specfiic ports on Linux, depends on several factors, you have not even indicated which Linux distrubution your using.   In both cases how it is done, is well documented, supply us your research effort.  Its also worth pointing out, that your apache configuration using internal ports, will have no effect on any client that has other ports blocked.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. I added the distro i'm using. The internal Apache config is complex, with rerouting, + my domain provider which does a "web forwarding", but I don't know if it's a HTTP 301 or something else under the hood...

Comment: You need to determine that information before we can help.

Comment: @Ramhound not really, all I want is "Let's visit this website like if my computer's networking would be limited to 80 and 443".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in Windows by creating a Firewall rule:
[image]